# ExpandableListView inside CardView doesn't change its parent height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I've the following structure - in order:

1) RecyclerView viewholder
2) CardView inside the viewholder ( Hieght is set to wrap_content)
3) ExpandableListView inside the cardview (Height is set to wrap_content)

The expandablelistview groups are collapsed by default when creating the viewholder. The problem is that when trying to expand a group, the height of CardView doesn't change even its height is wrap_contant. In other words, the viewholder height was set to the height of the expandablelistview when it was initialized at first.

So, a possible solution maybe to read the height of the whole (group + child) and when expanding a group set that height to CardView.

Any recommended solutions?

Comment: Which gradle version of recycler view you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem this is how I fixed it. There was issues with `WRAP_CONTENT` in `RecyclerView` that solved from version `23.2.1`.

By [Android Support Library 23.2.1](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html#revisions) update, all `WRAP_CONTENT` should work correctly.

Please update version of a library in gradle file OR to further :

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

solved some issue like Fixed bugs related to various measure-spec methods.

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7-recyclerview) and [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) links for more info.

> Make height of your `RecyclerView` and `CardView` parent to
>   `WRAP_CONTENT`.

Hope this will help SO user's.